# jQuery inArray returns number of select element

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

```
jQuery('#additional-channels-list select').live('change', function(){
    var current_id = parseInt(jQuery(this).val());
    select_values.push(current_id);
    console.log(select_values);
    console.log(jQuery.inArray(current_id, select_values));
});
```

I want to create multiple select without ctrl, so i need to store values in array. When i trying to check values `inArray` method returns to me the position of selected element in select list instead of information about current value in array. Where i am wrong?

Comment: *" When i trying to check values inArray method returns to me the position of selected element in select list instead of information about current value in array."* What makes you think that? From the code above, assuming that `select_values` is an array, your second `console.log` statement will give you the index of `current_id` in the array, not the select list.

Comment: Please stop using `.live()`. It's been deprecated for ages now. Use [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) (jQuery 1.7+) or [`.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) instead.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/ that's exactly what inArray does, it returns the index of the match.

Comment: @JamesAllardice with those it doesn't work

Comment: @Kirix - Read the docs that I linked to in my comment. They will work, but chances are you're using them wrong.

Comment: @Kirix Of course it does. Try `jQuery('#additional-channels-list').on('change', 'select', function(){ ... });`

Comment: "*information about current value in array*" - What else than the index do you expect? You have the `current_id` value already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

InArray returns item index, as from jQuery documentation:

> The $.inArray() method is similar to JavaScript's native .indexOf()
>   method in that it returns -1 when it doesn't find a match. If the
>   first element within the array matches value, $.inArray() returns 0.

Comment: Why retrieve the item? We did search for it, so we have it already.

Answer (score 0):

use the index returned from inArray to grab the according value in select_values.

Comment: Why grab the according value? We already have it, otherwise we couldn't have searched for it.